# Unexpected values for left and top attributes using jQuery.css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting unexpected output from `jQuery.css()`...

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/640/360" alt="" id="original_image" style="left:0px; top:0px;" />

<script>
  var original_image = $('#original_image');

  console.log(original_image.css('left')); //outputs 'auto' :(

  original_image.bind('load', function() {
    console.log(original_image.css('left')); //outputs 'auto' :(
  });

  $(function() {
    console.log(original_image.css('left')); //outputs 'auto' :(
  });

  setTimeout("console.log(original_image.css('left'))", 2000); //outputs '0px' :)
</script>
```

I would think the output in each one of the console.log() would be '0px'... what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a position style set on the image? It may ignore both the top and left attributes if it is not position: fixed, relative, or absolute.

Comment: @JamesHay YES, you're right, thanks! Post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to set a `position` attribute on your image element.

The default for this attribute is `position: static`. If you are using this style, the `top` and `left` attrbiutes will be ignored as an element with static position can not be moved outside of the document flow.